# Designing a User Table with different Identity providers in DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

The important attributes for the User Table are:

- unique id (uuid): to identify the user (and to be referenced later with other datasets for identity)
- social media id: FB, Google, Apple
- email id
- mobile no

User can login using either social media or mobile no or email. For this 3 cases, the searching needs to be done in the DynamoDB table for its existence.

So, what would be the ideal designing of this User table (with respect to keys) to ensure the performance as well as the purpose?

For better understanding of the Use Case:

**Use Case:**

1. User can register with Social Media (any of the FB or Google or Apple) along with mandatory detail like mobile and email
2. User can login using Social Media (any of the FB or Google or Apple) or Mobile No or Email ID (using OTP)
3. The Data volume will be on the higher side.

So, all this attributes to be stored alongside with the right design of the Primary Key to fetch information correctly during login.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I fully understand your use case, but I'd probably build it like this:

| PK | GSI1PK |
| --- | --- |
| `UUID#<uuid1>` | `GOOGLE#<google-id1>` |
| `UUID#<uuid2>` | `MOBILE#<number1>` |
| `UUID#<uuid3>` | `FACEBOOK#<facebook-id1>` |

The table has PK as it's partition key and GSI1PK as the partition key of a Global Secondary Index (GSI1).

If you want to check if there is a Google-User with a specific ID, you run a Query against `GSI1` with `GSI1PK=GOOGLE#<your-id>`. You can use the prefix for different identity sources.
Any queries against your own UUID can be executed against the Base Table.

You can also essentially flip the attributes, but this way it's easier to transition a user from one identity provider to another.

Comment: Have updated the Use Case information. Let me know if this helps.